# How to create reusable form and input components in Vue using slots?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

First, I am wondering whether I am on the right track with the patterns I am using for my application. Is it correct for me to create a reusable `BaseForm` component?

Another way to pose my question is: How do I model the parent component's data dynamically based on the child components I have included using slots?

I simply want to re use the same submit handler for all my forms. The submit handler should use the `action` and `method` props to determine how to configure `axios`, and the request body will be dynamic based on the `BaseInput` and `BaseSelect` components that are slotted within the `BaseForm` component.

Here's my sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-chaplygin-9e5u2?file=/src/App.vue

I am stuck on the `BaseForm.vue`'s `handleSubmit` method.

I could always just serialize the form data using vanilla JavaScript, but I feel that I should be doing it the Vue way. I am welcome to any opinions and advice. I am new to this framework, so I could be getting it totally wrong.

Comment: This course is really nice and helped me understand a lot of cool reusable patterns: https://michaelnthiessen.com/reusable-components Not a promo, just a guy making nice content.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are passing event handlers to child components vie function props.
But it's more common for React, not Vue.
In Vue you should just emit events and handle them in parent components.
Read more about it [here](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).
If you want to create reusable form component, one of the easiest ways is to do it with slots. You should create empty form with button (Cancel/Submit e.t.c) and add events for it.
Then you should just pass inputs to slot and that's all.
Working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-mclean-05jw7?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I agree that the slots feature in Vue holds the key, but your example doesn't solve my issue which is that I don't want to rewrite the submit handler logic for each form. You have the submit handler logic in the App.vue file, when it should be completely contained in the BaseForm.vue file

Comment: @devaent Which logic you don't want to copy, getting form data?

Answer (score 0):

I would just put a [template `ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on `<form>`, and create a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) with it, which will include all the form's named `<input>`s in its default slot:

```html
<form ref="form">...</form>
```

```js
const formData = new FormData(this.$refs.form)
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-goldstine-d2ozs?file=/src/components/BaseForm.vue:550-597)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the replies. The answer as to how to do this is too complex to make it worth doing **for my use case**.

I still have reusable form input components, but having a reusable parent form component with a reusable form submit handler is not the way to go. Even though it would be nice to keep it DRY, I think the solution would be overengineered (if even possible).

Here’s my final result: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-almeida-wpxbw?file=/src/App.vue